# Why is Lucifer the only angel with non-human face?

Tags: lucifer

Lucifer Morningstar's character is shown revealing his true devil face on several occasions. It is a face that is at least frightening, if not repulsive for the average human.

**Why is he the only angel to have this double face?**

I know that he is the fallen one, sent to Hell by his father but I do not recall in the series an explanation being given on why his face was distorted the way it is.

Any *Lucifer* series (that would be fantastic) or comics (still great) explanations are welcome.

<sup>As a last resort, a reference to a religious text would be fine (although Lucifer's interpretation changed considerably across the centuries, making a link with Satan and, generally speaking, it is quite a mess)</sup>

Comment: He's the only one who show his "real" face, not the only one who have it. And becuse he believe he look like this, this is what he show to others. There is no reason for angel (even fallen) to look like human.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, there is no reason to believe that Lucifer is the only one with a "real non-human" face. It's perfectly possible for the other angels to simply not have shown theirs.

It fits with Lucifer's character. He's the most honest of the angels (contrary to what you'd expect), so it makes sense for him to be the first to show his real face, literally and figuratively.

Secondly, Angels have struggled with their angelic features in several ways. Amenadiel's wings disappearing, Lucifer's wings reappearing when he cut them off, losing his devil face, his wings turning into leathery bat wings, ...

The key trick here is self-actualization. The angels can produce the angelic features that they believe themselves to be worthy of. So another way to explain Lucifer's devil face is that *he believes* himself to have a dark side, and therefore it manifests as a physical feature.

Note that self-actualization doesn't contradict the earlier point. Most angels think of themselves as the good guy more so than they actually are, whereas Lucifer tends to be on the other side of that spectrum. Maybe they have a real face and choose to never show it, maybe they just don't realize they can be two-faced and therefore the second face does not manifest.

Comment: It's also important to note that self-actualization doesn't just come consciously, but also sub-conscious. Amenadiel felt unworthy, Lucifer feels vilified. The other angels likely don't have scary or different faces because they are as God made them originally, and they are happy to be God's children. Lucifer is the only one who is consistently called a monster. Tell someone they are something enough times, and no matter how much they deny it, some part of them will start to believe!

Comment: I know it's probably not related to the show or comic, but it can be a provocative joke to God. Humans are his creation, so he could be mocking the image of god as well.

Comment: @fisheye: Given that part of Lucifer's upset revolves around being judged for being made the way he his, I doubt that he considers his devil face his own creation.

Answer (score 0):

So if you remember correctly or have gotten this far, Amenadiel mentioned that there may be self-actualization involved which makes them their own judges. With this involved, Lucifer mentions that he must have given himself his devil face. If this is the case, Lucifer had wanted to have this double face/devil face.

Someone may have theories on the whole self-judgement thing. Remember, Amenadiel was able to receive his wings back from seeing Charlotte dead. His emotions had shown and he had wanted to take her soul to Heaven. That was also what Charlotte had wanted, was to go to Heaven while getting rid of a burden from Hell.